# Cannot set Linearlayout params inside a Framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a Linear layout inside a Framelayout. What I would like to do is to add some margins programatically to the Linear layout based on the screen size.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.aba.webcampstest.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

         //oher stuffs
       </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout >
</ScrollView>
```

And my activity onCreate method contains

```
LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainerLayout);
int marginTopBottom = dpToPx((int)((dpHeight*8)/100),(int)density); //8%
int marginLeftRight = dpToPx((int)((dpWidth*6)/100),(int)density); //6%

LinearLayout.LayoutParams languageContainerLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
languageContainerLayoutParams.setMargins(marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom,marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom);
containerLayout.setLayoutParams(languageContainerLayoutParams);
```

I get the error when starting the Activity

> E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.aba.webcampstest, PID: 11723
>                     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:311)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
>                         at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1779)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                         at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:476)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setLayoutParams` [description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) :

> Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and these correspond to the different subclasses of ViewGroup that are responsible for arranging their children.

The `LayoutParams` type should be relative to the container of your `LinearLayout`, in this case `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` :

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams languageContainerLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
languageContainerLayoutParams.setMargins(marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom,marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom);
containerLayout.setLayoutParams(languageContainerLayoutParams);
```

Comment: You should first set Layout Parameters of your parent and then its child..in your case the Parent is #FrameLayout

Comment: LayoutParametres of view activity_main (FrameLayout) are already set in the xml. As are the params for mainContainerLayout, but Coder wants to change them at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Read the exception more carefully, especially this part:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

To clarify, when setting the LayoutParams of a view, you are declaring how your view is positioned inside its parent element.

So, for this example you provided use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

Update base on first comment:

Let me show you an example:

```
LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) 

findViewById(R.id.mainContainerLayout);
int marginTopBottom = dpToPx((int)((dpHeight*8)/100),(int)density); //8%
int marginLeftRight = dpToPx((int)((dpWidth*6)/100),(int)density); //6%

FrameLayout.LayoutParams languageContainerLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
languageContainerLayoutParams.setMargins(marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom,marginLeftRight,marginTopBottom);
containerLayout.setLayoutParams(languageContainerLayoutParams);
```

You are setting params for LinearLayout, but that layout is inside FrameLayout. So the LayoutParams of LinearLayout are of type `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

Which type of LayoutParams you should use is based on parents type in which your view is.

Comment: But I want to set the layout params to the linearlayout as I have shown before. Not for the Frame Layout....

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Coder Please check this snippet It will work

```
LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainerLayout);
int marginTopBottom = dpToPx((int)((dpHeight*8)/100),(int)density); //8%
int marginLeftRight = dpToPx((int)((dpWidth*6)/100),(int)density); //6%

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = containerLayout.getLayoutParams();
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).topMargin=marginTopBottom;
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).bottomMargin=marginTopBottom;
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).leftMargin=marginLeftRight;
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).rightMargin=marginLeftRight;
containerLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```